# How to use REGEXP_LIKE Constraint while creating Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Until last night, this worked:

```
CREATE TABLE UTENTE(
    ID_USER             CHAR(7)         PRIMARY KEY,
    USERNAME            VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PASSWORD            VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
    DATA_SIGNUP         DATE            DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    EMAIL               VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT          CK_REG_US       CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(USERNAME,'^[A-Za-z0-9]$')),
    CONSTRAINT          CK_REG_EM       CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(EMAIL, '^(\S+)\@(\S+)\.(\S+)$'))
);
```

Now if I do populate, see this error:

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (ADMIN.CK_REG_US) violated
```

From yesterday evening to today nothing has changed
example of insert that violated constraint

```
INSERT INTO UTENTE (id_user, username, password, data_signup, email) VALUES (SEQ_ID_USER.NEXTVAL, 'npalk0', 'xPtvZl9', '27-APR-2017', 'bbowden0@over-blog.com');
```

> I solved the problem, $, had to be removed, last night I do not know
>   why I put it, thanks to the help

Comment: someone is using characters other than the ones allowed in your 'username' constraint.

Comment: no, is all regular

Comment: Could you post an insert statement that violates the constraint?

Comment: ok, look in first message

Comment: I think `'^[A-Za-z0-9]$'` means only one character. Try `'^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'` or `'^[[:alnum:]]+$'` or `'^\w+$'`

Comment: Unless all your previous user names were exactly one character, this should not have worked till yesterday evening either. As Wernfried has said already: your constraint forces the user name to be a single character.

Comment: I solved the problem, $, had to be removed, last night I do not know why I put it, thanks to the help

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Please add your comment as an answer. That really answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression `'^[A-Za-z0-9]$'` means only one character.

Try `'^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'` or `'^[[:alnum:]]+$'` or `'^\w+$'` instead.

Note regarding your comment: If you remove $ like `'^[A-Za-z0-9]'` then username like `Rock and junk`  would be considered as valid!